# Pass optional table parameter to a cucumber step (ruby)

Tags: ruby, regex, cucumber, optional-parameters, optional-arguments

I have a step that can be like this:

```
Then  I 'eat' all food except
   | Bread |

Then  I 'drink' all food except
   | Bread |
   | Milk  |

Then  I 'eat' all food
```

I decided to put some of the arguments into the table, because otherwise it may be hard to read it.

Step definition in Ruby is:

```
Then(/^I '(eat|drink)' all food(?: except)?$/) do |action, exceptions|
  exceptions = exceptions.raw.flatten.map(&:strip) unless exceptions.nil?

  action == 'eat' ? method1(exceptions: exceptions) : method2(exceptions: exceptions)
```

It works fine, but not for the case when I don't pass the table argument ("Then  I 'eat' all food").
Is it possible to make a table argument optional?

Comment: Looks like it's not possible: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cukes/1w4h5Afz1Zs

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will work in cucumber, but as it's just a ruby block you can try to use param with splat. A single param will hold the whole parameter list then:

```
Then(/^I '(eat|drink)' all food(?: except)?$/) do |*params|
   # params is an array
   action = params[0]
   exceptions = params[1] # may be nil
   #...
end
```

[More on splats](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/rubys-splat-and-double-splat-operators-ceb753329a78)

Comment: thanks, yes looked into such options... they still don't cover all cases... So I just rewrote the step